# MSBuild.exe closing

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Apparently MSBuild.exe stays active after a build in VS2017 is aborted. I found that I should use **MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1** as an environmental variable to tell VS2017 to close the MSBuild.exe instance. Yet I cannot seem to find where I should enter this variable. Could anybody tell me in detail? I'm quite new to programming / VS2017.

Comment: Why do you want it to close? It might stay open for a reason

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I haven't had the chance yet to test since I'm not in the office. I will today. Thank you already for your detailed explanation tho!

Comment: @stijn It stays open for perfomance issues as LeoLiu said. But in my cases it blocks my files from being coppied. So I had to kill the process by hand each time before I could rebuild my project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Could anybody tell me in detail?

This is by design, since MSBuild 3.5. The child processes persist until 15 minutes has passed without use (ie without a build). This gives some performance gains in some cases. It's quite possible to disable it.

Related issues filed on MSConnect: [MSbuild proliferate](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/737860/msbuild-and-msbuildtaskhost-processes-proliferate-after-exiting-vs11-beta).

You can do this by setting and environment variable and/or msbuild arguments.

**Detailed steps set environment variable:**

To set the “MSBuildDisableNodeReuse” variable globally use the “Environment Variables” property page, which is accessed by **right-clicking Computer, clicking Properties, and clicking the “Environment Variables” button under the “System Properties” dialog window Advanced tab**:

[image]

Detailed step to set msbuild arguments:

```
msbuild YourApp.sln /nr:false /t:rebuild
```

See [Prepare the Development Environment](https://techdocs.ed-fi.org/display/ODSAPI20/Step+4.+Prepare+the+Development+Environment) for more detailed info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the link. I tried to google for a guide like that but I couldn't find it! Definitely deserves more credit.