# Pass command line options to Visual Studio MSBuild engine

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

How do I pass command line options (specifically `/nr:false`) to the Build engine run by Visual Studio. I found that I can pass properties by specifying them in a `PropertyGroup` in the project file, however I cannot find anywhere how to pass other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however I cannot find anywhere how to pass other options.

For the command line options `/nr:false`, you should set environment variable to pass Visual Studio MSBuild engine. That because the property of `/nr:false` is override the specified "system-level" properties.

According to the document [Microsoft/msbuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/MSBuild-Tips-%26-Tricks.md#msbuildexe-nrfalse):

[image]

We could to know, we have to set `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1` in the environment variables, however, when you check the `/property:` in the [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017#arguments), it set or override the specified **project-level properties**：

[image]

So we could pass properties by specifying them in a `PropertyGroup` in the project file. **This is because their corresponding switches are different**.

Note: You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534834/msbuild-exe-closing) for setting `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1` in the environment variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So is it not possible to do this? The problem with setting the environment variable is that it cannot be transferred with the project. Everyone, who wants to build this project, needs to set this up first, which doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Comment: @AndrásGeiszl, you just need set it once instead of every time. Even if you can set it in the project, you still need to set this up before you build your project, of course, if you think this is not smart enough, you can create a bat file to set the environment variable and execute it in the pre-build event. But if you want do this like the `/property` in the project file directly, I am worried that there is no such method (At least for me.).