# Internal failure occurred while running MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, bundler

Using Azure Devops and my builds started failing with the below error.
I cant find anything online related to it.

It is also intermittent it seems like.

> Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json MSBUILD : error MSB1025:
>   An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal
>   MSBuild Error: ContextID 94 should have been in the ID-to-project file
>   mapping but wasn't!

Comment: Does this issue occur on a private agent or a hosted agent?

Comment: Happens on an private agent.

Comment: If it only happens on the private agent, you can try to MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1 as an environmental variable, https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3362 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534834/msbuild-exe-closing

Comment: Let me try that quickly, will let you know